# check arguments in list unix

Tags: bash, unix

I have a list of names in a list (say name.txt) which has the set of name lists one by one.

**name.txt**

```
babu
praveen
kamal
sneha
```

This name will be passed as run time argument $1 in my bash script.
Now I have to do a match to check if the inputted name is in my list or not.

If it's not there then I will print saying invalid name and exit. Can you help me with this?

I have tried this with

```
if [[ "$1" != "babu" || "$1" != "praveen" || "$1" != "kamal" ... ]]; then
    exit
fi
```

but this doesn't look good professionally.

Is there any other simple and decent way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could use grep:

```
if ! grep -qFxf name.txt <<<"$1"; then
    exit
fi
```

- `-q` is "quiet mode" - the exit status indicates a match
- `-F` matches fixed strings, rather than regular expressions
- `-x` is a full line match, so names that are substrings won't match
- `-f` means that the list of patterns are contained within a file

The string contained within the first argument is passed to grep using a here string. This is a bash feature, so if you're using another shell, you could go with something like `if ! echo "$1" | grep -qFxf name.txt` instead (but the bash way is preferred as it saves invoking a subprocess).

If you want to ensure that any error output from grep is suppressed, you can add `2>/dev/null` to the command, as suggested in the comments. This prevents any messages sent to standard error from being displayed.

Comment: Maybe control `stderr` ? `grep -qFxf name.txt <<<"$1" 2>/dev/null` Just to insure no unwanted text?